# Error: module not found: javafx.controls 1 error

Tags: java, javafx, controls, jgrasp

So I wanted to restart my project, and deleted all the files I created that were related to this project (using jGrasp for Java). But then when I restarted my project and compiled the file I received the following error.

```
error: module not found: javafx.controls
1 error
```

Then I tried it on the old file that I was sure would work, but I got the same error. I was wondering how to fix it (I feel I might have deleted a file that I was not supposed to).

Comment: Maybe you can look at the backup you made before you restarted your project.  Your guess is as good as anyone's.....

Comment: Fixed spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you upgraded Java. JavaFX was removed in Java 11. See https://jgrasp.org/javafx.html for instructions on downloading JavaFX separately and configuring jGRASP to use it.

Comment: Thank you it help me fixing my problem!